# Difference between array and java.util.Collection implementation in terms of memory

Tags: java

When we say array memory allocation, it mean contiguous memory block allocated in heap area. So suppose there are 100k elements in an array, JVM will look in heap area where 100k contiguous memory blocks are free.

As per theory, this is not the case with java Collection. All the elements under collection will be allocated in heap memory by hashcode and it may or may not be contiguous memory blocks.

Now I am confused how Collection can work in this manner as Collection underlying implementation uses array only(e.g. ArrayList), which mean all properties of array will be valid with Collection also.

Need help to get clarity on this.

Comment: Collection is an interface with many implementations. Which one of them are you asking about?

Comment: we can take example of java.util.ArrayList

Comment: You could look at the source code of `ArrayList` if you want to know exactly how it works. You can find it in the file `src.zip` in  your JDK installation directory.

Comment: Thanks I checked ArrayList implementation which tells ArrayList also occupy contiguous memory location as array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Collection implementation is ArrayList then there is practically no overhead compared to Object[] , other implementations may occupy much more memory for holding the same number of elements. E.g. LinkedList has a node for each element:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

it is approx 5 times more memory for an element than Object[]

Answer (score 1):

As an ArrayList wraps arrays to provide resizable storage, it requires more memory than an array, which being a contiguous block of memory, knows already the current number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the factual memory consumption depends on the running Virtual Machine as an object's memory layout is not specified by the JVMS. Using a utility such as [*Java object layout*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) which comes with the OpenJDK, you can however analyze the actual instance sizes on HotSpot. The following outputs are valid for a 64-bit HotSpot v8_20b16 instance with compressed OOPS. In this setup, an `ArrayList` instance consumes:

```
java.util.ArrayList object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE     TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0    12          (object header)                N/A
     12     4      int AbstractList.modCount          N/A
     16     4      int ArrayList.size                 N/A
     20     4 Object[] ArrayList.elementData          N/A
Instance size: 24 bytes (estimated, the sample instance is not available)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

while an `Object[]` consumes:

```
java.lang.Object[] object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0    12       (object header)                N/A
     12     4       (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 16 bytes (estimated, the sample instance is not available)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

From this, it appears as if the `ArrayList` is significantly bigger than an array. However, we should rather look at actual instances in order to analyze the overhead that is caused by a collection's storage infrastructure and compute the *deep size*. Let's do this for an `Object[]` array and a list with each 1000 `new Object()` elements:

```
java.util.ArrayList instance footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
         1      4016      4016   [Ljava.lang.Object;
      1000        16     16000   java.lang.Object
         1        24        24   java.util.ArrayList
      1002               20040   (total)


[Ljava.lang.Object; instance footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
         1      4016      4016   [Ljava.lang.Object;
      1000        16     16000   java.lang.Object
      1001               20016   (total)
```

This is almost identical as the overhead of an `ArrayList` over an `Object[]` array is constant. Compared with a `LinkedList`, the size is quite drastically less by avoiding the `LinkedList$Entry`s:

```
java.util.LinkedList instance footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      1000        16     16000   java.lang.Object
         1        24        24   java.util.LinkedList
      1001        24     24024   java.util.LinkedList$Entry
      2002               40048   (total)
```

Do however not overestimate the impact of single allocations. Keep an eye on your memory consumption but rather use the collection type that suites your interest best. Optimization is appropriate if you observe a problem.